# SQL Server "Error converting data type varchar to bigint" from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run the following query in SQL Server and I'm getting the error

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    t.tableID, CAST(t.tableNumber AS bigint), i.woodName, i.woodYear  
FROM 
    dbo.table t WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[identity] i WITH (NOLOCK) ON i.tableID = t.tableID 
WHERE 
    ISNUMERIC(t.tableNumber) = 1 
    AND CAST(t.tableNumber AS bigint) = '1190159';
```

Comment: Without sample data, it is hard to say what the issue is.  That said, you could use try_convert()  or try_cast().  They will return a NULL rather than throwing an error

Comment: [Stop splattering your code with nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TRY_CAST()` instead:

```
WHERE TRY_CAST(t.tableNumber AS bigint) = 1190159;
```

Also, don't compare numbers to strings.

The problem arises because SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  So the `CAST()` can occur before the filtering for the `ISNUMERIC()`.